# Adding image URL to an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to build a very basic image carousel. I have an array of photos, a few of which will be stored locally, but I want to be able to add other pictures from around the web. I have it so clicking a button adds the URL of an image the user puts in a text box to an array. The URL gets added but in the console, when I examine the array it's not storing the URL, instead it stores image#url. How can I get this to store the URL? Thanks!

```js
var images = ['images/earth.jpg', 'images/shark.jpg', 'images/trolltunga.jpg'];
var blankWarning = document.getElementById("hidden");
var previousButton = document.querySelector('#previousButton');
var nextButton = document.querySelector('#nextButton');
var addImage = document.querySelector('#addImage');
var image = document.querySelector('img');
var url = document.getElementById('url');
var x = 0;

previousButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  x--;
  if (x < 0) {
    x = (images.length - 1);
  }
  image.src = images[x];
});

nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  x++;
  if (x === images.length) {
    x = 0;
  }
  image.src = images[x];
});

addImage.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (url === '') {
    blankWarning.style.display = 'inline';
    blankWarning.style.color = 'red';
  } else {
    images.push(url);
  }
});
```

```css
#image-wrapper img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-wrapper">
  <img src='http://placehold.it/100x100' />
</div>

<div id="button-wrapper">
  <button id="previousButton">Previous</button>
  <button id="nextButton">Next</button>
</div>

<div id="add-image">
  URL: <input type="text" id="url">
  <button id="addImage">Add an image</button><br>
  <p id="hidden">Image URL field cannot be blank</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: how to get value of text input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-how-to-get-value-of-text-input-field)

Comment: Your "url" variable is the whole element (from `var url = document.getElementById('url');`), not the url part. You probabably want to use `images.push(url.value);`

Comment: That was it! Thank you!